# warning LNK4099: PDB 'vc110.pdb' was not found with

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I am trying to get the .dll file in release mode for the performance problem of an existing application. The original debug mode .dll file does not give any problems but I get the following warnings while extracting the .dll file in release mode to overcome the license problems.

```
"Unhandled exception at 0x7ADA71F9 (AyonixFaceID.dll) in FaceMatch.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x001C1560."
```

I guess so, I get the error. [image: Could it be due to the warnings the compiler sends]?

Answer (score 0):

The [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/tool-errors/linker-tools-warning-lnk4099?view=vs-2019) gives explanations and methods:

PDB 'filename' was not found with 'object/library' or at 'path'; linking object as if no debug info

The linker was unable to find your .pdb file. Copy it into the directory that contains .object/library

Also, this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25843883/how-to-remove-warning-lnk4099-pdb-lib-pdb-was-not-found) may help you.