# How to fix(avoid) "no debug info" warning?

Tags: c++, directshow

Each time when I built my solution I get such warning notification. As far as I understand it means that my solution uses any libs that don't have files with debug symbols.

```
9>strmbasd.lib(amfilter.obj) : warning LNK4099: PDB 'BaseClasses.pdb' was not found with 'strmbasd.lib(amfilter.obj)' or at 'D:\Tier\x64\Debug\BaseClasses.pdb'; linking object as if no debug info
9>strmbasd.lib(amvideo.obj) : warning LNK4099: PDB 'BaseClasses.pdb' was not found with 'strmbasd.lib(amvideo.obj)' or at 'D:\Tier\x64\Debug\BaseClasses.pdb'; linking object as if no debug info
9>strmbasd.lib(combase.obj) : warning LNK4099: PDB 'BaseClasses.pdb' was not found with 'strmbasd.lib(combase.obj)' or at 'D:\Tier\x64\Debug\BaseClasses.pdb'; linking object as if no debug info
9>strmbasd.lib(mtype.obj) : warning LNK4099: PDB 'BaseClasses.pdb' was not found with 'strmbasd.lib(mtype.obj)' or at 'D:\Tier\x64\Debug\BaseClasses.pdb'; linking object as if no debug info
9>strmbasd.lib(wxdebug.obj) : warning LNK4099: PDB 'BaseClasses.pdb' was not found with 'strmbasd.lib(wxdebug.obj)' or at 'D:\Tier\x64\Debug\BaseClasses.pdb'; linking object as if no debug info
9>strmbasd.lib(wxlist.obj) : warning LNK4099: PDB 'BaseClasses.pdb' was not found with 'strmbasd.lib(wxlist.obj)' or at 'D:\Tier\x64\Debug\BaseClasses.pdb'; linking object as if no debug info
9>strmbasd.lib(wxutil.obj) : warning LNK4099: PDB 'BaseClasses.pdb' was not found with 'strmbasd.lib(wxutil.obj)' or at 'D:\Tier\x64\Debug\BaseClasses.pdb'; linking object as if no debug info
```

As far as I understood this is not critical if you are not going to debug this libs (actually I don't even know where the solution is using it... I read an article where was explanation how to fix such an issue, I need to reverse engineer a lib, then find a symbols, after a few magic actions more, so to make a long story short it's very complicated for such warning as for me.

Question is - is there a simple way to fix this warning or avoid it for these libs?

Comment: this question might be related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25843883/how-to-remove-warning-lnk4099-pdb-lib-pdb-was-not-found

Comment: @sergiom yeap, this link is what I mentioned in my question. I think it is too much magic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to  Build->Properties->Linker->Command Line

and add

```
/ignore:4099
```

[image]

Comment: looks exactly what I need. Just want to clarify (if you know) if there is a drawbacks?

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko - Drawback is that you won't get the warning even if you aren't having a pdb for a lib/obj which you have accidentally missed

Answer (score 1):

Missing PDB file means your output will have only partial debug information and will miss the part from statically linked library. Not a big deal but if you add directory with BaseClasses.pdb (`AdditionalLibraryDirectories` in Linker section of settings) the file will be found during linking process.

Suppressing a warning is a last resort to clean output log.

Comment: Something associated with a sound, maybe you can suggest smth https://stackoverflow.com/q/65023000/5709159