# Send wav file from python and receive in Unity: high pitch noizy result

Tags: python, c#, unity-game-engine, audio-source

I'm being stuck for two days by this seemingly simple problem of sending an audio file from Python to unity.
One of the files I used for testing can be downloaded here: [https://www2.cs.uic.edu/~i101/SoundFiles/BabyElephantWalk60.wav](https://www2.cs.uic.edu/%7Ei101/SoundFiles/BabyElephantWalk60.wav)

The sending code:

```
import socket

# Server configuration
HOST = '127.0.0.1'
PORT = 12345

# Read the audio file data (without the WAV header)
with open('BabyElephantWalk60.wav', 'rb') as audio_file:
    # Skip the WAV header (44 bytes)
    audio_file.seek(44)
    audio_data = audio_file.read()

# Create a TCP socket
server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server_socket.bind((HOST, PORT))
server_socket.listen()

print("Server listening on {}:{}".format(HOST, PORT))

# Accept a client connection
client_socket, client_address = server_socket.accept()
print("Connected to:", client_address)

# Send the audio data (without the WAV header)
client_socket.send(audio_data)

# Calculate the audio data length
audio_data_length = len(audio_data)
print("Sending audio data of length:", audio_data_length)
# Close the connections
client_socket.close()
server_socket.close()
```

and the receiving code in Unity:

```
using System;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.IO;
using UnityEngine;

public class RealTimeAudioReceiver : MonoBehaviour
{
    public AudioSource audioSource;

    private TcpClient client;
    private NetworkStream stream;
    private BinaryReader reader;

    private const int SampleRate = 22050;
    private const int Channels = 1;
    private const int BitsPerSample = 32;

    private byte[] receivedAudioData;

    private bool play=false;

    private void Start()
    {
        Debug.Log("Time.timeScale: " + Time.timeScale);
        ConnectToServer();
        
    }
    private void Update(){
        if(play){
            audioSource.Play();
            play=false;
        }
    }

    private void ConnectToServer()
    {
        try
        {
            client = new TcpClient("127.0.0.1", 12345);
            stream = client.GetStream();
            reader = new BinaryReader(stream);

            // Start receiving audio data
            StartCoroutine(ReceiveAudioData());
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Debug.LogError("Error connecting to server: " + e.Message);
        }
    }

    private System.Collections.IEnumerator ReceiveAudioData()
    {
        using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int bytesRead;

            while ((bytesRead = reader.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
            {
                memoryStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            }

            receivedAudioData = memoryStream.ToArray();
        }

        // Create and play the AudioClip
        CreateAndPlayAudioClip();

        // Clean up
        reader.Close();
        stream.Close();
        client.Close();

        yield return null;
    }


    private void CreateAndPlayAudioClip()
    {
        if (receivedAudioData != null && receivedAudioData.Length > 0)
        {
            AudioClip clip = AudioClip.Create("ReceivedAudio", receivedAudioData.Length / 4, Channels, SampleRate, false);
            float[] samples = new float[receivedAudioData.Length / 4];

            for (int i = 0; i < samples.Length; i++)
            {
                samples[i] = BitConverter.ToSingle(receivedAudioData, i * 4);
            }

            clip.SetData(samples, 0);
            audioSource.clip = clip;

            //int receivedLength = BitConverter.ToInt32(lengthBytes, 0);
            Debug.Log("Received audio data of length: " + receivedAudioData.Length);

            // // Adjust the playback speed based on the sample rate difference
            // float pitchFactor = (float)SampleRate / AudioSettings.outputSampleRate;
            // audioSource.pitch = pitchFactor;

            // audioSource.Play();
            play=true;
        }
    }
}
```

I've used Audacity to check the sample rate and channel and also printed out the number of bytes received. It looks all good. But when playing the audio it sounds like the audio is beinng accelerated and with lots of noize.
I'm so desperate and would be very grateful if someone could help!!!

Comment: Are you 100% sure your wave file is 22050 Hz mono with single-precision floats?  That's not a terribly common format, and your link doesn't work.

Comment: @TimRoberts I fixed the link and threw the file into https://www.maztr.com/audiofileanalyzer .. indeed it has 22050 sample rate and a 16-bit channel

Comment: It does have signed 16-bit integer samples.  So, you should immediately ask yourself why you have `BitsPerSample = 32` in your code.

Comment: @TimRoberts didn't use the BitsPerSample  in the original code. It's strange when I opened it in Audacity it's showing me 32-float.

Comment: Audacity converts ALL files to 32-bit floats for its internal computations.  It doesn't tell you what the file actually was.

Comment: Oh that's the reason!! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- I think the main issue is that you are receiving an audio tat uses a 16-bit channel, meaning always 16-bit (= 2 bytes) make one sample.

  You, however, always combine **4** bytes (32-bit) into one sample (`float`).

  You rather want to use `16-bit` samples.
- Further what you get is encoded in `16-bit Signed Integer` **not floats** => you need to convert them into Unity's float based data by dividing by the `Int16.MaxValue`.
- Note that your `.wav` file also has a [**header** of `44` bytes](https://docs.fileformat.com/audio/wav/#wav-file-header) that you would need to properly parse and / or at least skip!

like e.g.

```
const int SAMPLE_SIZE = sizeof(Int16);
const int WAV_HEADER_SIZE = 44; 

private void CreateAndPlayAudioClip()
{
    if (receivedAudioData != null && receivedAudioData.Length > 0)
    {
        var sampleCount = (receivedAudioData.Length - WAV_HEADER_SIZE) / SAMPLE_SIZE;
        AudioClip clip = AudioClip.Create("ReceivedAudio", sampleCount, Channels, SampleRate, false);

        float[] samples = new float[sampleCount];

        for (int i = 0; i < samples.Length; i++)
        {
            samples[i] = (float)BitConverter.ToInt16(receivedAudioData, WAV_HEADER_SIZE + i * SAMPLE_SIZE) / Int16.MaxValue;
        }

        clip.SetData(samples, 0);
        audioSource.clip = clip;

        play=true;
    }
}
```

See also

- [How to convert 16Bit byte array to audio clip data correctly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65023000/how-to-convert-16bit-byte-array-to-audio-clip-data-correctly)
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/68965193/7111561 **Use this instead! It fully solves your issues and works with different encoded files, not only for the one case you provided!**